# Laravel 5.4 Migrations?

Tags: laravel, migrations

Estou aprendendo `Laravel 5.4`, quando vou criar uma tabela relacionada  `one to one` não está criando a chave estrangeira, porém cria as tabelas normalmente.

Minhas Migrations:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',80)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('unidade_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('unidade_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('unidades')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUnidadesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('unidades', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nome',60);
            $table->string('cep',10);
            $table->string('logradouro',100);
            $table->string('numero',10);
            $table->string('bairro',60);
            $table->string('cidade',60);
            $table->char('uf',2);
            $table->string('telefones',30);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('unidades');
    }
}
```

Comment: Algum erro é reportado?

Comment: Qual erro esta dando?

Comment: Não, apresenta erro, apenas não cria o relacionamento

Answer (score 0):

Para a criação do foreign é necessário você rode primeiro o migrate da tabela **unidades** e apos isso o migrate da tabela **users**.

```
php artisan db:see --class=CreateUnidadesTable

php artisan db:see --class=CreateUsersTable
```

Comment: Pronto, vou testar assim!